# Why does optimizing with the -O(1/2/3) option interfere with scanf()?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program using gcc with optimization enabled.

```
gcc [name] -lm
```

works fine, but as soon as I add -O3 it gives me this warning:

```
warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It doesn't "interfere" in any way. It's just a friendly warning by gcc that you're ignoring the result of `scanf` (which may have failed to scan). You can proceed to ignore it or better, check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: You can use ”(void)scanf();” to tell the compiler you don’t care about the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this warning depend on the optimization level? *[from comment section]*

The main reason is that there are certain analysis enabled by different optimization levels.

The absolute best way is to do as the compiler tells you. Not checking the return value of various functions is something that is the source of many bugs. Just do something like this:

```
if(scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) != 2) { /* Handle error * }
```

and the warning will disappear.

If you instead decide that you know better than the compiler and simply want it to shut up, then you can also do as the warning tells you, even if it's not so obvious how it is done. Use this code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wunused-result"
```

That method can be used for a lot of warnings. In this particular case, it's however more conventional to cast the result:

```
(void)scanf( ...
```

but that does not always work.

Do note that all of these have their pros and cons. If you for instance for some reason are able to prove that all input from `stdin` will have the right form and that you never fail to read from it, then by all means, deactivate the warning. Another thing could be that you have special needs, like extreme performance and/or very limited resources, or maybe some other reasons, it could be a wise choice to do a risk analysis for it and see if the risk is acceptable.

But as a general rule, do not inactivate compiler warnings unless you are very, very certain that the thing the compiler is warning about will not cause trouble. "I don't want to see a a lot of warnings" is not a good reason for disabling warnings.

Comment: Very few things are “absolute.” This one is not.

Comment: @klutt instead of the pragma do ”(void)scanf();” to tell the compiler to ignore the return value.

Comment: @Fredrik That doesn't work for `wur` attribute. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66425

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, we've been over that multiple times. Another thing that is not absolute is the level of literaryness that is best in different situations, and I still have a higher belief in peoples ability to not assume that everything is mean to be take literary.

Comment: @klutt: It is not me I am concerned about. It is readers who are **new** to all this information and do take things literally because they do not have the background to discern “intentionally exaggerated statements,” a.k.a false statements. There definitely are times when things should be done differently from the professed orthodoxy, which is emphasized much too strongly by too many Stack Overflow participants, and students should not be mislead. Engineering often requires compromises, not hyper adherence to ideal standards. There is a simple criterion here: Tell the truth.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you compile it with -O2 or -O3 optimization level.
You can either suppress the warning by using the following gcc command options

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-result file.c -o file
```

or you can also declare a variable (if no memory constraints) to store the return value of scanf() which avoids the warning.

```
int unused __attribute__((unused));
    unused = scanf("%d",&e);
```

Comment: How about suggesting the OP **does** use the return value of `scanf()` to check for invalid or missing input?

Comment: Why does this warning depend on the optimization level?

Comment: The m option asks for a malloc(), and whether the malloc() or the input match to the format fails, the pointer or pointed to value is not valid, so you should always check the return of scanf() to see if you got everything.  Why optimization 2 or 3?  I guess when optimizing then this possibility becomes more obvious, but I'd agree it should always or never.  I am not a big scanf() fan as the error checking is so difficult, as if you get a return of EOF then you need ferror() to tell EOF from error, and if you get a low count >= 0, then you need to deal with your bad input values.